# Dynamic / Approximate Page Rank in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Does Neo4j (with APOC, GDSL, whatever) support a Dynamic (/ Incremental / Approximate) version of a PageRank algorithm?

For comparison, MAGE library of Memgraph has it:

- https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/query-modules/cpp/pagerank-online
- https://memgraph.com/blog/dynamic-page-rank-on-streaming-data

So I wonder if there's such (or similar) functionality in Neo4j. The idea is to not recalculate PR globally each time each node arrives, but to approximate it – until the next scheduled full recalculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to implement that yourself, if you want to put in the time and effort.

GDS provides the [Pregel API](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/pregel-api/) to allow users to create custom GDS algorithms.

Chapter 10 of the book [Graph Data Science with Neo4j](https://www.packtpub.com/product/graph-data-science-with-neo4j/9781804612743) actually shows how to create a custom PageRank algorithm with the Pregel API, so that should give you a huge leg up.

Comment: Thank you! It's much better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Page Rank algorithm in GDS:
https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/page-rank/

There is also a GDS Page Rank integration with Bloom:
https://neo4j.com/docs/bloom-user-guide/current/bloom-tutorial/gds-integration/#gds-pagerank

Comment: Thanks! It's a common PageRank implementation, not an incremental version I'm asking about.